# Fitting projective transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

Given set of points in $3D$ ( $X = (x_1, x_2, x_3)$, $Y = (y_1, y_2, y_3)$ ), how can I fit transformation from $X$ to $Y$?

As far as I know this is called projective transformation.
Here is example of $X$ and $Y$.
Blue and red lines in $X$ are parallel, but they are not parallel in $Y$.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you use the term "projective"?  Are the output coordinates constrained in some way?

Comment: @Commodore64: At first, I thought it's possible to find appropriate transformation matrix from X to Y. But this transformation is non-linear and it's not possible to represent non-linear transformation matrix in general. There are some tricks, such as using homogenous coordinates or Jacobian matrix, but they make things more complicated.

Comment: have you looked at least squares techniques?